# Ctrl+F doesn't work in JavaFX WebView

Tags: webview, javafx-2, javafx

In JavaFX WebView I can view view html pages. Although shortcut to find a word doesn't work there (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

How can I enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView does not support this functionality.

I raised a [feature request](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23383) for it.  The feature is not scheduled for implementation. You can vote for it if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the find functionality yourself.

An example would be to create a new HBox in your FX scene that opens when it detects the CTRL+F event with a TextField for typing into.  After this, you'll need to make it so that every time you type in the TextField it will fire off an event to a method where you implement some Javascript that searches through the DOM of your current page based on what you typed in to find.  You can also make it so that your script highlights the word it found, amongst other find related tasks.